# Does the membership seeder tool to add new FBA users, use the createuser method?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, forms-authentication, sql-server, membership-provider

Does the membership seeder tool to add new FBA users, use the createuser method?

Here is the link from where I downloaded it:

http://cks.codeplex.com/releases/view/7450

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This it the code from MemberFrm.vb in the source code you linked to:

```
newUser = Membership.CreateUser(userName, PwdTxt.Text, userName & "@" & DomTxt.Text, _
 "YourDog", "Fido", True, userStatus)
```

So yes